# Show Message When Click On asp:Gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I would like to show alert() when user clicks on asp:gridView. in column 1

i has been a gridview that fill by linq;

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridInbox" runat="server" Width="813px" CellPadding="4" 
                        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">


                    </asp:GridView>
```

2.
how can==>column[1].width=10;

Answer (score 1):

Update :

If it is bound column

```
<asp:BoundColumn onClientClick="javascript:alert('blah blah');" />
```

If it is template column

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div onclick="javascript:alert('Clicked');">
<asp:label text="blah blah" />
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You mean something like this?

```
<div onclick="javascript:alert('Clicked');">
<asp:gridview runat="server">
</asp:gridview>
</div>
```

Comment: Its a bound column or template column?

Comment: a tag gridview raw that fill by linq